# Given $f(z)=\sum c_nz^n$ what does it mean to express the sum of the odd and even in terms of $f$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f(z)=\sum c_nz^n$. Express the sum of the even terms,$\sum c_{2n}z^{2n}$, and the sum of the odd terms, $\sum c_{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$, in terms of $f$.

---

I'm just wondering what it means to state it "in terms of $f$." I haven't come across this before.

Does it mean something like $f(z)=\sum c_{2n}z^{2n}+\sum c_{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$? Or am I on the complete wrong track?

Thanks!

Comment: The phrasing "in terms of $f$"  is indeed a bit vague, but I think it means finding an expression for those sums involving only $f(z)$ and $f(-z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $f(z)=\sum c_nz^n$, then what is $f(-z)$? Can you use this to isolate the even or odd terms in the power series expansion?

Comment: If $f(z)=\sum z^n$ then I know $f(z)=1+z+z^2=\frac{1}{1-z}$ and for the even part it would be $f(z)=\sum z^{2n}=1+z^2+z^4=\frac{1}{1-z^2}$. But how would I go about adding in the $c_n$ and $c_{2n}$ and the entire odd portion?

Comment: In general $f(-z)=\sum (-1)^nc_nz^n$, so $\frac{f(z)+f(-z)}{2}=\sum c_{2n}z^{2n}$. A similar trick works to get the odd indices.

Comment: So would $f_e(z)=\frac{f(z)+f(-z)}{2}=\frac{1}{1-z^2}$ and $f_o(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(-z)}{2}=\frac{z}{1-z^2}$?

Comment: You have the right expressions for $f_e$ and $f_o$, but I don't know where the last part is coming from, unless you have a specific example for $f$ in mind.

Comment: Oh ok! I had read somewhere that $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$ but that must have been for a specific example like the geometric series then! That makes sense! Thanks so much :)